# Android skipped frame skipped when sending data from wear to the phone

Tags: android, multithreading, accelerometer, wear-os

I followed several tutorials to build an Android app that collects my Android wear accelerometer (x,y,x). I want to send the collected data to the phone for recognition purpose to analyze it later. Everything works fine, I have two buttons to start/stop the collection. I collect the data and store it in a List, then after the stop button hit, I use a thread to send it to the phone.
 I have some questions:

1. Why I'm getting `Skipped XXX frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.` when I print the data on the phone?
2. Is using AsyncTask right here? or should I use Thread?

This is my code:

```
public void onStartClicked(View view) {
    Log.v("StartClicked", "in on start clicked");
    googleClient.disconnect();
    updating = 1;
}

//when stop button clicked, the gathered data 
//will be sent to the phone
public void onStopClicked(View view) {
    Log.v("StartClicked", "in on stop clicked");
    googleClient.connect();
    updating = 0;
    new LongOperation().execute("");
}
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        Sensor mySensor = sensorEvent.sensor;
        accelerationTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        if (updating == 1) {

            if (mySensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
                float x = sensorEvent.values[0];
                float y = sensorEvent.values[1];
                float z = sensorEvent.values[2];


                double m = Math.sqrt((sensorEvent.values[0] * sensorEvent.values[0]
                        + sensorEvent.values[1] * sensorEvent.values[1] + sensorEvent.values[2]
                        * sensorEvent.values[2]));

                SensorDataItem item = new SensorDataItem(m, sensorEvent.values[0], sensorEvent.values[1], sensorEvent.values[2], new Date());
                dataQueue.add(item);
            }
        }
    }
//when the button stop pressed, this happens
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        //
        NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult nodes = Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(googleClient).await();
        for (Node node : nodes.getNodes()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                MessageApi.SendMessageResult result = Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(googleClient, node.getId(), path, dataQueue.toString().getBytes()).await();
                if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    Log.v("myTag", "Message: {" + message + "} sent to: " + node.getDisplayName());
                } else {
                    // Log an error
                    Log.v("myTag", "ERROR: failed to send Message");
                }

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.interrupted();
            }

        }
        return "Executed";
    }
```

Comment: Is this code running on the watch? And on which device are you getting the "Skipped xxx frames" message?

Comment: This is running on the watch, the message I got is on the phone side

Comment: Then, have you moved your data processing off the UI thread on the phone side?

Comment: Nothing happens on the phone UI, I just write to a file and log out what is being received.

Comment: And is that filesystem operation happening on the UI thread?

Comment: yes it is, you mean in the main activity?